# How do I invoke a method only when my object (model) is first created in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5, instantiation

I'm using Rails 5.  I want a method invoked on my model only when the model is first created.  I have tried this ...

```
class UserSubscription < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :scenario

  def self.find_active_subscriptions_by_user(user)
    UserSubscription.joins(:scenario)
        .where(["user_id = ? and start_date < NOW() and end_date > NOW()", user.id])
  end

  after_initialize do |user_subscription|
    self.consumer_key = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(10)
    self.consumer_secret = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(25)
  end

end
```

but I noticed this gets called every tiem I retrieve a model from a finder method in addition to its begin created.  How can I create such functionality in my model?

Comment: You could replace that finder method with a scope: `scope :active_subscriptions_by_user, -> (user) { where("user_id = ? and start_date < NOW() and end_date > NOW()", user.id) }`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `after_create` (from [active record docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)) or `after_create_commit` which was introduced in Rails 5 as a shortcut for `after_commit :hook, on: :create`.

`after_create` always executes after the transactions block whereas `after_create_commit` does so after the commit but within the same transactions block. These details likely don't matter here, but it's a new capability if you need that extra control for ensuring the model state is correct before you execute the after call.

Comment: Thanks.  Does this mean after_create executes before the object is saved to the db?  Basically I'm trying to set values for the object because they won't exist when the object is initially created.  HOwever, once they are set, I don't want to touch them.

Comment: `after_create` executes after the object saves to the db. `before_create` executes before the object saves to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Pyrce's answer is good. Another way is to keep the `after_initialize` method but only run if it's a new record:

```
after_initialize :set_defaults 
def set_defaults
  if self.new_record?
    self.consumer_key = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(10)
    self.consumer_secret = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(25)
  end
end
```

(It's generally considered better to not override the `after_initialize` method. Instead provide the name of a method to run, as I did above.